# Setup external libraries with laravel mix

Tags: laravel-5, webpack, laravel-mix

I need to use an external library on web pack with laravel-mix. On web pack I should do something like this *as described in the [webpack docs](https://webpack.github.io/docs/library-and-externals.html)*

```
{
    output: {
        // export itself to a global var
        libraryTarget: "var",
        // name of the global var: "Foo"
        library: "Foo"
    },
    externals: {
        // require("jquery") is external and available
        //  on the global var jQuery
        "jquery": "jQuery"
    }
}
```

But I can do this with laravel mix?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

On your *`webpack.mix.js`* file

Just below

```
let mix = require('laravel-mix');
```

Add the following code

```
mix.webpackConfig({
    externals: {
        "jquery": "jQuery"
    }
});
```

Add any other external as required. For example I decided to load external React and ReactDOM so my config is

```
mix.webpackConfig({
    externals: {
        "react": "React",
        "react-dom": "ReactDOM"
    }
});
```

Note that you can override any webpack default config inside `mix.webpackConfig` parameter object just like we did `externals` here